# Why composite is expanded by text field?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, e4

I created a text field which used `GridLayout` and I set the 3rd parameter of the `GridData` (`grabExcessHorizontalSpace`) to true. The `Text` field is not getting wrap into multiple line when I set a very long sequence of non-whitespace characters won't be split into lines. The `Composite` is expanded by text filed.

Below is my code:

```java
Composite composite = new Composite(m_shell, SWT.NONE);
composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, true));
composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.LEAD);
label.setText("Label");
label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false));

Text text = new Text(composite,SWT.MULTI|SWT.BORDER|SWT.WRAP|SWT.V_SCROLL);
GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false);
gd.heightHint = 2 * text.getLineHeight();
text.setLayoutData(gd);
text.setText("trweghjfbfdshjfghjreuyhjfghkjhjhjsdghjreewhjdfghjhjgfdhjsdghjtreuytrehjdfghjhjdfgh8irtrhjghjhjdfghjdfghjfghjdfg");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `widthHint` to 0 together with the `horizontalAlignment` to `SWT.FILL` makes the text fill all availible space in its column, but not grow more that that. Instead it wraps as desired:

[image: Screenshot]

I tried this on Windows 10 with SWT 3.103.2. Greg seems to have got [another result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535192/why-composite-is-expanded-by-text-field/53536325#comment93943839_53536325) on Mac.

```java
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, true));
composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.LEAD);
label.setText("Label");
label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false));

Text text = new Text(composite, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);
GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false);
gd.heightHint = 2 * text.getLineHeight();

// Added widthHint
gd.widthHint = 0;
text.setLayoutData(gd);
text.setText("trweghjfbfdshjfghjreuyhjfghkjhjhjsdghjreewhjdfghjhjgfdhjsdghjtreuytrehjdfghjhjdfgh8irtrhjghjhjdfghjdfghjfghjdfg");

shell.pack();
shell.open();

while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
    }
}

display.dispose();
```

Comment: Thank you Lii.. It's worked for me in windows 10 but I did not test it Mac/Linux..

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are calling `pack` on the `Shell` to complete the layout. This causes controls to be sized at their preferred size - the preferred size for a `Text` control is the size with no wrapping.

If you want the shell to be a specific size you can `layout` on the shell without calling `pack`. The text should then wrap.

Alternatively specify a `widthHint` for the `Text` control.

Comment: I don't want to specify any widthHint. I used GridLayout for avoid the specific width.

Comment: There aren't any other choices that I can think of

Comment: @DebasishHalder, greg-449: Is a possible solution to set `widthHint` to 0 for the `Text`? Since the `Text` has `horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL`, it will still grow to fill the container, will it not?

Comment: @Lii That doesn't work (at least on macOS) it just gives a very narrow field.

Comment: This is working fine for the Windows 10 but did not test it Mac/Linux...@greg-449, @Lii